# Transitive dependencies are not found when using composite builds with custom publish metadata

Tags: gradle, groovy, dependencies

Given the following three projects (foo, bar, and app), where app depends on bar depends on foo, I'd like to be able to simply install bar in project app and have library foo automatically installed as well.  This does work correctly with the following scripts:

## Project 'foo' build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id "maven-publish"
}

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}

group = "com.test2.foo"
version = "0.0.1"

def distZip = file("${buildDir}/dist.zip")
def distFile = file("${buildDir}/Foo.txt")

tasks.register("createDistFile") {
  outputs.file(distFile)
  doLast {
    distFile.delete()
    distFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
    distFile.text = "foo output 1"
  }
}

tasks.register("assembleZip", Zip) {
  dependsOn "createDistFile"
  from distFile
  archiveName = distZip.name
  destinationDir distZip.parentFile
}

publishing {
  publications {
    main(MavenPublication) {
      artifact(distZip) {
        builtBy tasks.named("assembleZip")
      }
    }
  }

  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
  }
}
```

## Project 'bar' build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id "maven-publish"
  id "base"
}

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}

group = "com.test2.bar"
version = "0.0.1"

def distZip = file("${buildDir}/dist.zip")
def distFile = file("${buildDir}/Bar.txt")

tasks.register("createDistFile") {
  outputs.file(distFile)
  doLast {
    distFile.delete()
    distFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
    distFile.text = "bar output 2"
  }
}

tasks.register("assembleZip", Zip) {
  dependsOn "createDistFile"
  from distFile
  archiveName = distZip.name
  destinationDir distZip.parentFile
}

artifacts {
  "default" distZip, {
    builtBy tasks.named("assembleZip")
  }
}

publishing {
  publications {
    main(MavenPublication) {
      artifact(distZip) {
        builtBy tasks.named("assembleZip")
        pom.withXml {
          def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

          def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
          dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', "com.test2.foo")
          dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', "foo")
          dependencyNode.appendNode('version', "0.0.1")
        }
      }
    }
  }

  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
  }
}
```

## Project 'app' build.gradle

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}

configurations {
  api
}

dependencies {
  api "com.test2.bar:bar:0.0.1"
  // This should be automatically installed when bar is installed
  // api "com.test2.foo:foo:0.0.1"
}

tasks.register("installLibs", Copy) {
  dependsOn configurations.api
  destinationDir = file("${buildDir}/libs")
  configurations.api.each { config ->
    from zipTree(config)
  }
  doFirst {
    destinationDir.deleteDir()
  }
}
```

## The Problem

When using the above scripts, this can be verified by running `installLibs` in project app and verifying that both `Bar.txt` and `Foo.txt` are installed into the `build/libs` directory.

However, if I change the `settings.gradle` file in project 'app' to be this:

```
rootProject.name = 'app'

includeBuild '[PATH TO BAR PROJECT]'
```

Then if I run `./gradle installLibs` again for the app project, I find that `Foo.txt` is no longer installed.  Is there a way to manually specify this build metadata for project bar, so then when it is used with includeBuild that its transtive dependencies get included?

Comment: By the way - I noticed that transitive dependencies + composite builds works fine with java projects, so this must be possible somehow